# How to share localStorage on same domain but different protocol (http vs https)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, local-storage

I need to share the localStorage on `https://example.com` to `http://example.com`

The site runs on https, but there's a specific path (`/viewer`) that needs to be http so it can embed other sites in an iframe (if it wasn't the browser would block mixed content since https cant load http pages on an iframe).

How can I access the localStorage of `https://example.com` within `http://example.com`?

If it's not possible, are there any workarounds?

Comment: The policy is that the protocol must match. One solution would be to store the data on your server, and fetch them when needed.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in localStorage.

But, you can handle a cookie with javascript as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie in both http and https.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are considering two different protocols as different domain so the local storage is different for both protocols we can do that using post message api where we setting data in local storage we call a function in our iFrame and pass that data as message.

Use this code in your `http` page

```
var data = "Smith";
localStorage.setItem("lastname", data);
let o = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
o.contentWindow.postMessage({
  'func': 'set_data_function',
  'message': data
}, '*');
```

Now we need to receive that data in our `https` and set that data for our `https` too in same way we can remove data from local storage of both protocols.

And this code in your `https` page which is you loading iframe.

```
// this is the function which is we calling from our http
window.set_data_function = function (data) {
    console.log('called from parant');
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", data);
}

$(function () {

    window.addEventListener('message', receiver, false);
    (window).set_data_function = this.set_data_function.bind(this);
    function receiver(e) {
        // also we able to check the origin this will make our script secure 
        console.log(event.origin);
        if (event.origin !== 'http://localhost:8081') {
            return;
        }

        var data = event.data;
        console.log(typeof (window[data.func]));
        window[data.func].call(undefined, data.message);
        if (typeof (window[data.func]) == 'function') {
            window[data.func].call(undefined, data.message);
        }
    }

});
```

hope it will help you best of luck